# How can I merge different array objects based on one element

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I merge these two arrays?

```
array1 = [
  { image: 'image1', title: 'title1' },
  { image: 'image2', title: 'title2' },
  { image: 'image3', title: 'title3' },
];

array2 = [
  { downloadLink: 'downloadLink1', fileName: 'fileName1' },
  { downloadLink: 'downloadLink2', fileName: 'fileName2' },
  { downloadLink: 'downloadLink3', fileName: 'fileName3' },
];
```

I want to get the following result:

```
array3 = [
  { image: 'image1', downloadLink: 'downloadLink1', fileName: 'fileName1' },
  { image: 'image2', downloadLink: 'downloadLink2', fileName: 'fileName2' },
  { image: 'image3', downloadLink: 'downloadLink3', fileName: 'fileName3' },
];
```

Comment: Is there any matching rule or you just want to merge them by array index? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this:

```js
const array1 = [
  { image: 'image1', title: 'title1' },
  { image: 'image2', title: 'title2' },
  { image: 'image3', title: 'title3' },
];

const array2 = [
  { downloadLink: 'downloadLink1', fileName: 'fileName1' },
  { downloadLink: 'downloadLink2', fileName: 'fileName2' },
  { downloadLink: 'downloadLink3', fileName: 'fileName3' },
];

let result = []

array1.forEach(({image},index) => {
  result[index] = {image, ...array2[index]}
})

console.log(result)
```